Systematic and comprehensive definition and classification of a mode (electromagnetism)
I am currently having a hard time understanding which is the deciding factor/quality for the definition of a light mode. I will give a couple of examples and also what I think regarding as to how we define a mode, but I am not sure and perhaps someone has a better explanation for this problem.
In our lecture the first mode that we mention was the gauss mode. The definition is based on the profile of the intensity of the em wave.
After that we are introduced with Hermite-Gaussian and Laguerre-Gaussian modes, where the intensity profile is used as the criteria for the different modes. I believe in these modes, we look at the transverse distribution of the electric field. But I am not sure.
Then we proceed with the electric field in different structures i.e waveguides, optical resonators (cavity).
Each structure has it's own modes, i.e:
Modes in a waveguide are:
TEM: $\vec E$, $\vec H$ are perpendicular to $\vec k$
TE: $\vec E$ is perpendicular to $\vec k$
TM: $\vec H$ is perpendicular to $\vec k$
Here the mode definition is done based on the relationship between $\vec E$, $\vec H$ and $\vec K$.
In cavities:
For the classification of a mode the indices q,m and n are used.
q is the longitudinal mode order, which physically translates to the nr. of wavelengths alongside the distance between the mirrors of the cavity. While m and n are the transverse mode orders, which i believe have to do with the intensity distribution of the field.
But we also mentioned modes when we are in free space, for which I have no idea what types of modes we have and which is the determine factor for the classification.
So, as you can see there is no clear way for the classification of modes.
